# css: ul li ul li height

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to set the height for the Games menu like all the other menus, but it is not working. What is wrong?

This is my code:

```html
<ul class="menu">
   <li class="item-474 current active"><a href="/">News</a></li>
   <li class="item-482 deeper parent">
      <span class="separator">Applications</span>
      <ul>
         <li class="item-483"><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="item-484"><span class="separator">Appearence</span></li>
</ul>
```

```
#left-menu ul.menu {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

#left-menu ul.menu li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  background: url("img/menu1.png");
  width: 208px;
  height: 31px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#left-menu ul.menu li ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  background: url("img/menu2.png");
  width: 208px;
  height: 31px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Can you describe or show the expected outcome?

Comment: Is this a question or a statement? :) [Edit: sorry, -1 for not being specific]

Comment: How it should look like?

Comment: I'm sorry. It was mistake: I want to set height for "Games" like other menus

Comment: Next time put the question into the question. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is that li's have fixed height. So when you add second level list there is no space for them.

Change height to min-height and everything will works.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FJV8b/